# Change background images using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have 31 images and I want to display them one after another as the background of a div. I only want it to change when the user hovers over the div. My problem right now is that it just flips through all the images really fast. I am attempting to use setTimeout, but it isn't working. How can I make the delay work?
The name of the div is About_Me_Block and the images are called frame1.gif,frame2.gif ...etc

Here is my code:

```
function changeImg(counter) {
    $('#About_Me_Block').attr("style", "background-image: url(playGif/frame" + counter + ".gif);");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hoverAnimate = []
    "use strict";
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseenter(function() {
        hoverAnimate[0] = true;
        var counter = 0;

        while (hoverAnimate[0]) {
            console.log(counter);
            setTimeout(changeImg(counter), 1000);
            counter++;
            if (counter === 32)
                hoverAnimate[0] = false;
        }
    });
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseleave(function() {
        hoverAnimate[0] = false;
        $(this).attr("style", "background-image: url(play.jpeg);");
    });
});
```

Comment: What animation do you want?

Comment: Not animate using jQuery. It is just flipping through a set of images to make it look like it is a gif i guess. The problem is I need a delay to make it actually visible otherwise it just flips really fast to the last image.

Comment: when you call `setTimeout(changeImg(counter), 1000)`, you're actually directly calling your change function, not telling setTimeout to call it at some later time. you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a function to pass to setTimeout that will do what you want: `setTimeout(changeImg.bind(this, counter), 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't wait for the function to end, it works lile threading in other languages.

To achieve a what you want, you need to call setTimeout from the changeImg function.

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hoverAnimate = []
    "use strict";
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseenter(function() {
        hoverAnimate[0] = true;
        counter = 0;
        changeImg();
    });
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseleave(function() {
        hoverAnimate[0] = false;
        $(this).attr("style", "background-image: url(play.jpeg);");
     });
 });

function changeImg() {
    $('#About_Me_Block').attr("style", "background-image: url(playGif/frame" + counter + ".gif);");
    counter++;
    if (counter < 32 && hoverAnimate[0]) {
        setTimeout(changeImg, 1000);
    } else {
        hoverAnimate[0] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how I can change my code to make it work?

Comment: @AllenHuan I include it

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, but there is still a small bug there sometimes between changing images you can see the back without any image and it flashes really quickly. However I don't think there is much we can do about that since it is a timing problem :/

Comment: @AllenHuang That happens, becauss you need to load in the image

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to preload the image so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Mouse over the image then mouse off then mouse over again. This should cause it to jump twice, because the setTimeout was called for the first mouse over which will wait for one second. Mousing off does not remove the first setTimeout. So, before the setTimeout timer has expired you mouse over again calling setTimeout again. This creates another timer. Therein when the first expires it will change the image followed by the second.

Answer (score 1):

the reason they happen all at once is because `while` statement doesn't have delay, so all `setTimeout` will be set up at the same time, thus, calling `changeImg` all at once.

To solve this problem, you can replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval`. Instead of using `while`, you can just call `setInterval` like

```
var counter = 0;
var myTimer = setInterval(changeImg, 1000);
```

and update `counter` inside `changeImg` every time it gets called. After looping, don't forget to

```
clearInterval(myTimer)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to read up on how `setTimeout` works. It essentially places a reminder to run a function after a given amount of milliseconds have passed. So, when you do `setTimeout(changImg(counter), 1000)` you are calling `changImg(counter)` which returns `undefined`. Therein producing this `setTimeout(undefined, 1000)` which is why it flips really fast.

---

So, you can use `bind` to allow the function to be called later with that parameter built in. Also, make sure you remove the reminders once done with `clearTimeout`.

```
function changeImg(counter) {
    $('#About_Me_Block').attr("style", "background-image: url(playGif/frame" + counter + ".gif);");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hoverAnimate = false, id;
    function loop(counter) {
        if(hoverAnimate || counter < 32) {
            changeImg(counter);
            id = setTimeout(loop.bind(this, counter++), 1000);
        }
    }
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseenter(function() {
        hoverAnimate = true;

        id = setTimeout(loop.bind(this, 0), 1000);
    });
    $('#About_Me_Block').mouseleave(function() {
        hoverAnimate = false;
        // Don't want a reminder for a random counter to wake up.
        clearTimeout(id);
        $(this).attr("style", "background-image: url(play.jpeg);");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods for timers - setTimeout and SetInterval (single / repeating)

```
// setInterval is also in milliseconds
var intervalHandle = setInterval(<yourFuncToChangeImage>,5000);

//this handle loop and make example loop stop
yourelement.yourEvent = function() {
clearInterval(intervalHandle);
};
```